# Display data on HTML page from Json file with mixed data. single data + array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Hi  i make an call and receive a Json file in return. The file contains both data and data in a array.
Now i try to list this data to a simple table. I don't know how display the data inside the array . The **address** data is in a array

```
    <?php   
                      $data = file_get_contents("http://xxxxxxxx/service/v20/list?orgKey=xxxxxx");  
                      $data = json_decode($data, true);  
                      foreach($data as $row)  
                      {  

                        echo '<tr>
                        <td>'.$row["caseKey"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["caseNumber"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["officeId"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["status"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["propertyType"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["propertyClass"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["openHouseDate"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["openhouseSignupRequired"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["price"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["downPayment"].'</td>

                        <td>'.$row["monthlyOwnerExpenses"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["monthlyGrossPayment"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["monthlyNetPayment"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["daysForSale"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["priceReductionPercent"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["sizeArea"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["sizeLand"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["sizeBasement"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["sizePatio"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["sizeGarage"].'</td>


                        <td>'.$row["numberRooms"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["numberFloors"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["constructionYear"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["reconstructionYear"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["energyBrand"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["Header"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["Description"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["Tag"].'</td>

                        <td>'.$row["address"].'</td>  /* array type */
                        <td>'.$row["Address[0].Roadname"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["Address.Roadnumber"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["Address.Floor"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["Address.Door"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["Address.Zipcode"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["address.city"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["Address.placename"].'</td>

                        <td>'.$row["realtorName"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["realtorPhone"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["realtorEmail"].'</td>


                        <td><img src="'.$row["primaryPhoto"].'>"</td>
                        </tr>';

                      }  
                      ?>
```

Comment: Eg. the roadname for the array-elementno. "recno" would probably be accessible by using $row["Address"][recno]["Roadname"] etc. (that would be logical). But how to display the data that is stored in the array, depends on the structure of the array. 
I think it would help if we see the json data that you receive. It suffices if you just post one JSONified record. Please anonimise any privacyrelated data.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just :

```
<td>'.$row["address"].'</td>
```

To:

```
<td>';  
foreach($row["address"] as $addr){
      echo $addr."<br>" ;       
}
echo '</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should provide an example of the json to udnerstand your question.

i think your promlem is here:

```
<td>'.$row["Address[0].Roadname"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["Address.Roadnumber"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["Address.Floor"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["Address.Door"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["Address.Zipcode"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["address.city"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["Address.placename"].'</td>
```

if you want to access a nested array structure $row["Address[0].Roadname"] should be:

```
$row["Address"][0]["Roadname"]
```

means the array is:

```
[
    "Address" => [
        0 => ["Roadname" => "value"]
    ]
]
```

in your example you provide $row["Address.Roadnumber"] that should be:

$row["Address"]["Roadnumber"]

means the array is:

```
[
    "Address" => [
        "Roadnumber" => "value"
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked fine to list all data in the array, however i need only part of the data in the array

```
<td>';  
foreach($row["address"] as $addr){
      echo $addr."<br>" ;       
}
echo '</td>
```

I modified the code as below and that worked fine to display part of the array.
i also realized that my code was misspelled  / Adress => adress  / Roadname => roadname

Thank you for your support / Tomas

```
<td>'.$row["address"]["roadname"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["address"]["roadnumber"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["address"]["zipcode"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["address"]["city"].'</td>
```